# How to obtain the row from a mouse click on JEditorPane containg an HTML table

Tags: java, html, swing, html-table, jeditorpane

Is there a way to obtain the row index within an HTML table defined in a JEditorPane? I tried viewToModel method but this isn't what I was expecting.

```
pane.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println( pane.viewToModel(e.getPoint()) );               
    }

                ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy/lazy answer: *of course you cannot*. Even in a pure html page, you need some javascript to achive this.
JEditorPane can't handle javascript (i think, maybe i'm wrong), so no chance.

Now, you can use a different approach:

- Change a field (or create a new one) with a link.
- The link will have as url somenthing like `#rowXXX`, where XXX is the number of the row.

```html
<a href="#row001">Some field</a>
```

- Add a `HyperlinkListener` to the jEditorPane:

```java
editor.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    try {
                        String rowcode = e.getDescription();
                int row = Integer.parseInt(rowcode.replace("#row",""));
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Now in `row` you should have the number of the row.

**Full example**

```java
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

public class App extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String HTML = "<html><table border=\"1\"><tr><td><a href=\"#row001\">First row</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href=\"#row002\">Second row</a></td></tr><tr><td><a href=\"#row003\">Third row</a></td></tr></table></html>";

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JEditorPane editor;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    App frame = new App();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public App() {
        setTitle("HTML TABLE CLICKABLE");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 408, 235);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        editor = new JEditorPane();
        editor.setEditable(false);
        editor.setContentType("text/html");
        contentPane.add(editor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        editor.setText(HTML);

        editor.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    String rowcode = e.getDescription();
                    int row = Integer.parseInt(rowcode.replace("#row",""));

                    System.out.println(row);
                }
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: yes, sorry. Just checked the code. You need to use getDescription and not getURL. This because #row001 is not a valid URL and cannot be parsed. getDescription will always return the value of the href. i've update the answer

Comment: e.getDescription()   yep, you beat me to it :)

Comment: As long is wrapped in a link, sure.

Comment: can't find my image, even though I gave it an absolute path in the html … will keep digging … thanks!